# Is it possible to update or delete the order items from the order with out creating the new order?

Tags: delete, edit-order, reorder

In my case, an order should be modified after the review.
Order items can be removed or quantity will be modified from the order.

I knew the Re order would the do the purpose by manually deleting the old order once re order is completed. But I do not want to change the order id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It too bad idea to `change order item and order details,delete order` after order placed.As per as magento system ,there lot of calculation like `grand total,subtotals,tax,shipping cost` are depends on  order items.

If you will done `any change at order items and delete items` then it will create huge issues on calculation sales.

**So it will better idea to you create an new order for this case and cancel old order.**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But in the customer point of view it will be the same order with different order id that's what I required to update the current order. Yes, it is hard to change the current order items. Let's see!